# By pressing the button do not move to the desired page with this command in js window.location.href

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have a problem when I click the send button in the table it does not take me to the requested page, I checked all sides in db and server side and i do not understand why i get error 400
code angular
add link can download the code http://www.filedropper.com/finalproject_3

```
 <script>
                      (function (app) {
                app.controller('FrameController', FrameController)
            })(angular.module('TestApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMaterial']));
        </script>
    </head>
<body ng-controller="FrameController">
    <div ng-cloak>
        <md-content>
            <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
                <div flex="50">
                    <div class="mdl-grid">
                        <md-card>
                            <md-card-title>

                                <md-card-title-text>
                                    <span class="md-headline"> </span>
                                </md-card-title-text>
                                <md-card-title-media>
                                    <md-progress-linear md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-linear>
                                    <div class="md-media-lg card-media"></div>
                                </md-card-title-media>
                            </md-card-title>
                            <md-card-content>
                                <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                                <md-select ng-model="searchText" placeholder="choose place" class="md-no-underline">
                                    <md-option value="Club">Club</md-option>
                                    <md-option value="Bar">Bar</md-option>
                                    <md-option value="Dance-Bar">Dance-Bar</md-option>
                                    <md-option value="Resturant">Resturant</md-option>
                                    <md-option value=" coffe-shops">Coffe-shops</md-option>
                                </md-select>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="enter the place you want" ng-model="searchText.Title">
                           </md-card-content>
                            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">

                            </md-card-actions>
                        </md-card>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Title</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <th>Street</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat=  "row in rows | filter:searchText">

                                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{row.Title}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.Description}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.Phone}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.City}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.Street}}</td>
                                <td><button ng-click="send(row)">Send</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
</md-content>
```

**code js**

```
function FrameController($scope, $http) {
    var data;
    $http.get('/api/places/frames/frame').then(function (response) {


        $scope.rows = response.data.map(function (item) {
            return new MenuEventModel(item);

        });

        data = angular.copy($scope.rows);

        $scope.loaded = true;
        console.log($scope.rows);


        $scope.send = function (row) {
            console.log(row);

            window.location.href = 'Detail.html?Id=' + row.Title;

        };
    });


}
```

**code c# server side**

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Places/Details/Detail")]
        public IHttpActionResult Test(int Id)
        {
            var service = Services.SqlPool.PlacesService;
            using (var conn = service.StartConnection())
            {
                var result = service.SelectAsList<Models.EventsByDays>(conn, "spGetDetailsAboutPlace", new SqlParameter("@Id", Id));

                service.StopConnection(conn);

                return Ok(result);
            }
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // any operation which aim to free memory is welcomed here :)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
 window.location.href = 'Detail.html?Id=' + row.Title;
```

with

```
var linkStart = 'Detail.html?Id=' + row.Title;
$state.go(linkStart);
```

(And dont forget to add $state with $http and $scope)

EDITED:

```
function FrameController($scope, $http, $state) {
var data;
$http.get('/api/places/frames/frame').then(function (response) {


    $scope.rows = response.data.map(function (item) {
        return new MenuEventModel(item);

    });

    data = angular.copy($scope.rows);

    $scope.loaded = true;
    console.log($scope.rows);


    $scope.send = function (row) {
        console.log(row);

        var linkStart = 'Detail.html?Id=' + row.Title;
$state.go(linkStart);

    };
});
```

}

OR USE $window instead of $state.

Comment: (Im making the assumption that your "'Detail.html?Id=' + row.Title;" gives a valid route)

Comment: I tried to change but it did not help and added code sever side

Answer (score 0):

change your html to:

```
<head>
    <script>
        (function (app) {
            app.controller('FrameController', FrameController)
        })(angular.module('TestApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMaterial']));
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="FrameController">
    <div ng-cloak>
        <md-content>
            <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
                <div flex="50">
                    <div class="mdl-grid">
                        <md-card>
                            <md-card-title>

                                <md-card-title-text>
                                    <span class="md-headline"> </span>
                                </md-card-title-text>
                                <md-card-title-media>
                                    <md-progress-linear md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-linear>
                                    <div class="md-media-lg card-media"></div>
                                </md-card-title-media>
                            </md-card-title>
                            <md-card-content>
                                <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                                <md-select ng-model="searchText" placeholder="choose place" class="md-no-underline">
                                    <md-option value="Club">Club</md-option>
                                    <md-option value="Bar">Bar</md-option>
                                    <md-option value="Dance-Bar">Dance-Bar</md-option>
                                    <md-option value="Resturant">Resturant</md-option>
                                    <md-option value=" coffe-shops">Coffe-shops</md-option>
                                </md-select>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="enter the place you want" ng-model="searchText.Title">
                            </md-card-content>
                            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">

                            </md-card-actions>
                        </md-card>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Street</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | filter:searchText">

                            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{row.Title}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.Description}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.Phone}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.City}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.Street}}</td>
                            <td><button ng-click="send($event, row)">Send</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</body>
```

and change your javascript code to:

```
function FrameController($scope, $http, $window) {
        var data;
        $http.get('/api/places/frames/frame').then(function (response) {
            $scope.rows = response.data.map(function (item) {
                return new MenuEventModel(item);

            });
            data = angular.copy($scope.rows);
            $scope.loaded = true;
            console.log($scope.rows);

            $scope.send = function (e, row) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(row);
                $window.location.href = 'http://...' + 'Detail.html?Id=' + row.Title;
            };
        });
    }
```

Comment: i added link to download code https://uploadfiles.io/2osoe  yes this error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: if you cannot try to make absolute URL to redirect.

Comment: what's this link?

Comment: I've found your problems, but they are a lot. please allow me to to check all of these.

Comment: it works, you have `window.location.href = 'Details.html?Id=' + row.Title;` in  your `frames.js` that you must change it to `window.location.href = 'Detail.html?Id=' + row.Title;`

Comment: `Details.html -> Detail.html`

Comment: i change to   window.location.href = 'Detail.html?Id=' + row.Title; but it's not help

Comment: Do you have any special character in the row.Title?

Comment: Like `% * \ ~ ^ `?

Comment: you can upload the code file with the changed you do. I dont have a special character

Comment: maybe you have Skype talk there

Comment: @Daniel Shmayovich I'm OK but we need a shared screen.  what about team-viewer?